# Bluetooth disconnects when scanning barcode

Tags: java, android, printing, bluetooth, zxing

I am using a Bluetooth printer and zxing barcode scanner for this project. My problem is that after I have the Bluetooth printer connected and I try to scan a barcode, using zxing, it disconnects the Bluetooth printer. Here is my code.

```
package com.zj.printdemo;

import com.zj.printdemo.R;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import com.zj.btsdk.BluetoothService;
import com.zj.btsdk.PrintPic;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PrintDemo extends Activity {
    Button btnSearch;
    Button btnSendDraw;
    Button btnSend;
    //Button btnClose;
    Button clearBtn;
    Button btnBarcode;
    EditText edtContext;
    EditText edtContextQTY;
    EditText edtPrint;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    BluetoothService mService = null;
    BluetoothDevice con_dev = null;
    private static final int REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE = 1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //Button clearBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //edtContext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
        mService = new BluetoothService(this, mHandler);
        if( mService.isAvailable() == false ){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
        }

        clearBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        OnClickListener ClearOnClickListener = new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                edtContext.setText("");
                edtContextQTY.setText("");
            }
        };
        clearBtn.setOnClickListener(ClearOnClickListener);

        btnBarcode = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBarcode);
        OnClickListener BarcodeOnClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == R.id.btnBarcode) {
                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(PrintDemo.this);
                    integrator.initiateScan();
                }
            }
        };
        btnBarcode.setOnClickListener(BarcodeOnClickListener);
}

    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if( mService.isBTopen() == false)
        {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        }
        try {
            btnSendDraw = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btn_test);
            btnSendDraw.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            btnSearch = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
            btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            btnSend = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            //btnClose = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.btnClose);
            //btnClose.setOnClickListener(new ClickEvent());
            edtContext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_content);
            edtContextQTY = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_contentQTY);
            //btnClose.setEnabled(false);
            btnSend.setEnabled(false);
            btnSendDraw.setEnabled(false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("������Ϣ",ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mService != null)
            mService.stop();
        mService = null; 
    }

    class ClickEvent implements View.OnClickListener {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == btnSearch) {           
                Intent serverIntent = new Intent(PrintDemo.this,DeviceListActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(serverIntent, REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE);
            } else if (v == btnSend) {
                String msg = edtContext.getText().toString();
                String msgQTY = edtContextQTY.getText().toString();
                if( msg.length() > 0 ){
                    mService.sendMessage("ItemID:"+msg+"\n","ItemQTY:"+msgQTY+"\n");
                }
            } //else if (v == btnClose) {
                //mService.stop();}
             else if (v == btnSendDraw) {
                String msg = "";
                String lang = getString(R.string.strLang);
                //printImage();

                byte[] cmd = new byte[3];
                cmd[0] = 0x1b;
                cmd[1] = 0x21;
                if((lang.compareTo("en")) == 0){    
                    cmd[2] |= 0x10;
                    mService.write(cmd);
                    mService.sendMessage("Congratulations!\n", "GBK"); 
                    cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                    mService.write(cmd);
                    msg = "  You have sucessfully created communications between your device and our bluetooth printer.\n\n"
                          +"  the company is a high-tech enterprise which specializes" +
                          " in R&D,manufacturing,marketing of thermal printers and barcode scanners.\n\n";


                    mService.sendMessage(msg,"GBK");
                }else if((lang.compareTo("ch")) == 0){
                    cmd[2] |= 0x10;
                    mService.write(cmd);
                    mService.sendMessage("��ϲ����\n", "GBK"); 
                    cmd[2] &= 0xEF;
                    mService.write(cmd);
                    msg = "  ���Ѿ��ɹ��������������ǵ�������ӡ����\n\n"
                    + "  ����˾��һ��רҵ�����з�����������������Ʊ�ݴ�ӡ��������ɨ���豸��һ��ĸ߿Ƽ���ҵ.\n\n";

                    mService.sendMessage(msg,"GBK");    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handler BluetoothService
     */
    private final  Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
            case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                switch (msg.arg1) {
                case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTED:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect successful",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //btnClose.setEnabled(true);
                    btnSend.setEnabled(true);
                    btnSendDraw.setEnabled(true);
                    break;
                case BluetoothService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                    Log.d("��������","��������.....");
                    break;
                case BluetoothService.STATE_LISTEN:
                case BluetoothService.STATE_NONE:
                    Log.d("StateNone","�ȴ�����.....");
                    break;
                }
                break;
            case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_CONNECTION_LOST:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Device connection was lost",
                               Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //btnClose.setEnabled(false);
                btnSend.setEnabled(false);
                btnSendDraw.setEnabled(false);
                break;
            case BluetoothService.MESSAGE_UNABLE_CONNECT:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to connect device",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            }
        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth open successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                break;
            case REQUEST_CONNECT_DEVICE:
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String address = data.getExtras()
                            .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS);
                    con_dev = mService.getDevByMac(address);

                    mService.connect(con_dev);
                }
                break;
            case IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE:
                IntentResult scanningResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                if (scanningResult != null) {
                    String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
                    String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
                    //formatTxt.setText("FORMAT: " + scanFormat);
                    edtContext.setText(scanContent);
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "No scan data received!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
    private void printImage() {
        byte[] sendData = null;
        PrintPic pg = new PrintPic();
        pg.initCanvas(384);
        pg.initPaint();
        pg.drawImage(0, 0, "/mnt/sdcard/icon.jpg");
        sendData = pg.printDraw();
        mService.write(sendData);
    }
}
```

My goal is to connect the printer, scan a barcode, and print a tag with the ID and quantity. Manual entry works, the printer works, and the barcode scanning works. Its only when you use the barcode scanner after you connect the printer that it will disconnect the printer.